# Angular material input fields not working when using css backface property

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I used [this](https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/LmWoWe) example in order to make the 3d flip animation

```
<div class="scene scene--card">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card__face card__face--front">front</div>
    <div class="card__face card__face--back">back</div>
  </div>
</div>
<p>Click card to flip.</p>
```

Using the following css

```
.scene {
  width: 200px;
  height: 260px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  margin: 40px 0;
  perspective: 600px;
}

.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform 1s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.card.is-flipped {
   transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card__face {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 260px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 40px;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.card__face--front {
   background: red;
}

.card__face--back {
  background: blue;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

In my case I have forms on each face. Without material all works will

[Demo without material](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-backface-basic?file=src/app/app.component.html)

But when I add material I cannot use the input fields on the backface (click on Sign up to flip)

[Demo with Material](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-backface-material?file=src/app/app.component.css)

Somehow it seems that the input fields from the front interfere with the backface input fields. I tried to set an `z-index` but that didn't do anything useful. Any help would be appreciated!

Update: Must have been my mistake, a prober z-index on the faces seems to work: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-backface-material-ekcays?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: I am not sure if the first demo you have is actually working as expected. The card only flips when I click the text "Click card to flip", but not when I click on the card directly.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.is-flipped .card__face--front {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-backface-material-yrnnth?file=src/app/app.component.css

Comment: Nice, I must say that I tried this, but probably did something wrong. But how come that we have to do this, and cannot fix this with other stuff like `z-index`. One way or the other, the backface element is on top, so I would expect it to work

Comment: Super weird, now it seems to work with a z-index on the faces: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-backface-material-ekcays?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the click-event to the card instead of the text: "Click card to flip".
Add this `(click)="isFlipped=!isFlipped"` to the card instead:

```
<div class="scene scene--card" (click)="isFlipped=!isFlipped">
  <div class="card" [ngClass]="{'is-flipped': isFlipped}">
    <app-login (reg)="isFlipped = true" class="card__face card__face--front">

    </app-login>
    <app-login (reg)="isFlipped=false" class="card__face card__face--back"></app-login>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can of course add this click-listener to any other element that is more suitable than the entire card. You probably need to prevent the event from propagating if you don't want the card to flip if you press the input fields or the buttons. 
I also added a click-listener to the "forgot password button" as an example:

```
forgotPasswordClick(event: MouseEvent){
    event.stopPropagation();
}
```

[Here is a working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-backface-material-6s4qwr?file=src/app/app.component.ts)